# org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dependency-injection

I am getting this error while running my application :  `org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]`

My configuration class :

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:META-INF/spring/jdbc.properties")
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env; 

    @Bean(name="dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() throws PropertyVetoException{
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();                              
        dataSource.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("db.driverClass"));          
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("db.jdbcUrl"));
        dataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("db.user"));                               
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));                               
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(50);                               
        dataSource.setMinPoolSize(5);                               
        dataSource.setMaxConnectionAge(1800);                             
        dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(1800);                               
        dataSource.setAutoCommitOnClose(false);                               
        dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(5);  

        return dataSource;
    }  

    @Bean(name="sessionFactory")
    @Scope("singleton")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();                               
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("db.dialect"));                                                 
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", "0");                               
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("c3p0.acquire_increment", "1");                           
        localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

        return localSessionFactoryBean;
    }              

     @Bean(name="transactionManager")
     public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
         HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
         transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

         return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

I ran actually into this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750036/cannot-unwrap-to-requested-type-javax-sql-datasource-spring-hibernate-java-con) which talks about the same issue. However I am wondering if it is a sort of bug in hibernate5 that has not been fixed yet or does it relate to something else. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey, I am not a hibernate expert, but your methode returns a 'DataSource' and you create in it a 'ComboPooledDataSource'. Is this correct? Or is here the issue?

Comment: ComboPooledDataSource implements DataSource interface and SessionFactory has an attribute of type DataSource. So I suppose that the type references used in the source code above are correct. If you have any further opinion you are more than welcome

Comment: @user-x220 can you please provide your `pom.xml`?